# Activity Enter- and Exit-Transition on the same time without fading

Tags: java, android, android-activity, transition, android-transitions

I want to create an Activity Transition with the Transition-API in Android KitKat. Activity B shall slide up over Activity A. Activity A shall stay.

Code Activity A:

```
getWindow().setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.no_transition)
                .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
                .setDuration(400));
```

Code Activity B:

```
getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                .excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true)
                .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
                .setDuration(400));
```

This is working, but as well as Activity B slides in, Activity A is fading out.
Also I want the both transition to take place a the exact same time. Therefore I tried to use:

```
getWindow.setWindowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true);
```

and

```
getWindow.setWindowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(true);
```

While the transitions with the overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.stay-Method takes place at the same time, I can't achieve that with the KitKat Transition API. The enter Transition starts befor the Exit Transition

I need to take the new API for excluding the Statusbar background from the transitions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?